# Nested CollectionView with dynamic height based on content whilst using MagazineLayout and Carbon

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, nested, uicollectionview

I am creating a CollectionView where the cell has a nested CollectionView. I am using [Carbon](https://github.com/ra1028/Carbon) to display the cells in the collection view and using [MagazineLayout](https://github.com/airbnb/MagazineLayout) for the layout. There is only one Component which holds two views, a label and another CollectionView both inside of a vertical stack view with top, left, bottom and right constraints. Here is a picture of what the expected layout should be and it is similar to a "thread" of messages where a reply adds a new thread and so on. The nesting gets larger with more threads:

[image: Solution Example]

At the moment the label displays correctly but the CollectionView height does not grow dynamically based on the cells inside of the CollectionView as shown below.

[image: Current]

I have tried using this [example](https://medium.com/@rozan.ktm/uicollectionview-inside-uitableviewcell-dynamic-height-based-on-uicollectionviewcell-height-86b3257e85c6) which subclasses UICollectionView and overrides layoutSubviews and intrinsicContentSize. This works to a point apart from the layout glitches and some of the nested CollectionViews heights change when scrolling.

I have also looked into using UICollectionViewFlowLayout as the EstimatedItemSize can be set which does most of the heavy lifting with setting the height dynamically. However, this solution cannot be used as MagazineLayout is a subclass of UICollectionViewLayout.

I can send an example project or more information if needed. Thank you for any help.

Comment: This will get exponentially more complicated with each thread being added. I would do it with a single collectionView without any nesting where cell subclass has the flexibility of indenting the content to left/right depending on thread count/depth/level etc.

Comment: Yes thats a good idea. It just sacrifices the threaded cells belonging to a parent but I can create some logic around that with the idea of depth/levels. I could also put them into a section so that they can be moved together on the collection view

Comment: @AndrewHarris I guess you could try using indexPaths with lengths more than two. So every "level" means an index in an indexPath. The documentation says that in UICollectionViews indexPaths do not have to be limited to a pair, but they could be longer. So an item "2.2.1" would have an indexPath 1-1-0. I remember it definitely worked long ago (~ iOS 8), but animated updates failed. I investigated and fixed that issue long time ago, and that should be a demo: https://github.com/storoj/UICollectionView-bug.

Comment: @AndrewHarris ... Find and set FIX_ENABLED=1, and play with buttons in the UI to figure out what they mean :)